# Shared functionality in an abstract method

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns

I have an abstract method which sets a graphical item's label. There are different types of items, all of which inherit from an abstract base class which has a "setLabel()" method.

The different items do different things when they set a label, but at the end they should all do the same thing, which is a series of housekeeping activities. I know I can create a method in the base class to do these chores and then call that in each of the implementations, but that is bad because among other things if I forget to call it from one of the implementations, it will create a bug.

What is a good way to structure this?

Here is example code (how I am doing it now in Java):

```
final public void _setLabel( String s ){
    if( s.trim().equals( "null" ) ) return;
    StringBuffer sbError = new StringBuffer();
    if( ! _setConstantValue( s, sbError ) ){
        Error.vShowError( "failed to set value: " + sbError );
        return;
    }
    sLabel = s;
    _update();
    _updateProperties();
    if( _isGroupMember() ) this.nodeGroup._update();
}
```

There is an abstract method "_setLabel" in the base class, so all my subclasses MUST implement this method. The last three lines in the method are always the same:

```
_update();
_updateProperties();
if( _isGroupMember() ) this.nodeGroup._update();
```

Right now, I just copy and paste these lines into each implementation, but I would rather they get done in the base class somehow, so I can guarantee that they always occur. These must be called **after** everything else.

**SOLUTION:**

Based on the marked answer below (thanks to user3736255), the solution is to use a non-virtual interface in C++ or a template method in Java (which is equivalent). So the new base class code is:

```
final public void _setLabel( String s ){
    __setLabel( s );
    _update();
    _updateProperties();
    if( _isGroupMember() ) this.nodeGroup._update();
}

abstract protected void __setLabel( String s );
```

Each subclass implements the `__setLabel` method which is called by the template method `_setLabel` in the base class.

Comment: Have you considered using an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)?

Comment: @CanadianDavid that would be overkill, I am just trying to set a label here.

Comment: There isn't a truly generic way to accomplish this. Each language is going to have its own set of inheritance constraints that change how this is accomplished, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Why did you tag it with C++ if you wanted all the answers to be in Java?

Comment: @CanadianDavid Because I thought it might have the same answer in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the Non-virtual interface pattern: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Comment: That would be a solution, but how do I do that in Java?

Comment: In Java use the template method pattern in the same way as NVI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
class Base() {
   public:
   void setLabel();

   protected:
   virtual void doSetLabel();

   private:
   houseKeepingBefore();
   houseKeepingAfter();
}

void Base::setLabel() {
   houseKeepingBefore();
   doSetLabel();
   houseKeepingAfter();
}
```

But, this will not solve your problem, if you have a `houseKeepingInbetween`.

Comment: I only need to do housekeeping after. How do I do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a decorator that extends the base and is created with an appropriate instance of the graphical item. It is the responsibility of the decorator to invoke the housekeeping activities. All clients invoke the decorator instead of the actual graphical item. Note: I am assuming that all invocations to the graphical item are through defined/declared methods in the base. 
 
You could perhaps also utilize aspects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: Not sure if that would solve the OP's problem since they would still have to remember to decorate each method that needs housekeeping in all subclasses.

Comment: Not sure that would be the case if the decorator is the proxy to all subclasses.